# How can i create auto increment file version?

Tags: c#, version, auto-increment

I have resource file which got the version number of the file. i want to update the file version. i want my version file to increment from 5 upwards.

let me put it in way which everyone will understand.

1. Broswer for the file,
2. the user will select the file and load into datagridview1 with its data
3. when the user click newbutton, it copies datagridview1 and load it to datagridview2 but, it will load it without data because we creating new file when we newbutton,
4. it will be loading empty datagridview
5. file version must increase from 5 upwards
6. file version will increase from the file when you save

All this is working beside the fact that every-time when i click newbutton my version reset and start from five again and i don't want it to start from five again. I want it to keep on continuing or carry from last file created.(just like insert on SQL) 5.6.7.8.9.10.11.12.13 .........

I have checked this [Fixed Assembly Version with Auto Incremented File Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307435/fixed-assembly-version-with-auto-incremented-file-version) but i don't understand it well for my question

How do i out increment file version every time you create new file ?

Resource file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <root>
      <resheader name="resmimetype">
       <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
       </resheader>
     <resheader name="version">
       <value>5</value>
    </resheader>
   <resheader name="reader">
  <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms,     Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
  <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms,   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
 </root>
```

New Button

```
  private void btnNewfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(PathSelection);
            XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::resheader[@name = 'version']/value");
            int iversion = Convert.ToInt32(myNode.InnerText);
            iversion++;
            lblversion.Text = iversion.ToString();
    }
```

Save button

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int iversion = Convert.ToInt32(lblversion.Text.ToString());

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(outputFilePath);
            XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList CnodesList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::data");

            XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::resheader[@name = 'version']/value");
            myNode.InnerText = iversion.ToString();   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user click new, you'll load the source file with version, increase it by 1 and save the source-file keeping the version for your new file.

Comment: I don't understand well what you saying or i should do to work.

Comment: I didn't see but there is a version number in the input file allready. So read the input file and also save to that file when you have increased the version number.

Comment: I got it working ,Look at my updated code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great that it's working! I can't really tell where you save the files. But make sure that you save the old file right when you've have read the and incremented version number if there are more than one user working at the same time.

I cannot mark your post as answer if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Resource File

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <root>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
   <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
   </resheader>
 <resheader name="version">
   <value>5</value>
</resheader>
```

New button

```
private void btnNewfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(PathSelection);
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::resheader[@name = 'version']/value");
        int iversion = Convert.ToInt32(myNode.InnerText);
        iversion++;
        lblversion.Text = iversion.ToString();
}
```

Save button

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iversion = Convert.ToInt32(lblversion.Text.ToString());

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(outputFilePath);
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList CnodesList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::data");

        XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::resheader[@name = 'version']/value");
        myNode.InnerText = iversion.ToString();   
}
```